# Code Igniter - Anchor Reutrn False?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to return false with using the anchor function in CI, as it's sending me to another page, rather than loading ajax.

Here's my code:

```
<li id="addclient"><?php echo anchor('site_add_client', 'Clients', array('onclick'=> "content_ajax_client()")); ?>  </li>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add return false in with the onclick...

```
<?php echo anchor('site_add_client', 'Clients', array('onclick'=> "content_ajax_client(); return false")); ?>  </li>
```

Et voila...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to Robimp's answer, you could return false inside your js function.

```
function content_ajax_client(){
    //your code here
    return false;
}
```